# retrieving saved data from a boxplot figure in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a boxplot that is saved as a figure in Matlab. Unfortunately, I do not have the original data. How do I retrieve the data using code or the user interface?

Answer (score 0):

You may be more precise on your question but here is an example with a simple `plot`. It shoule be the same with `boxplot`. It is all about getting axes children.

```
open myfig.fig; % open your fig file
h = gca; % get the handle of the current axes
hPlot = h.Children; % The children of the axes should be the plot line
XData = hPlot.XData; 
YData = hPlot.YData;
```